# How do I add the extensions.gnome.org repository to dnf in Fedora 31?

Tags: fedora, gnome, repository, gnome-shell, dnf

In the GNOME Software application I can install extensions directly from extensions.gnome.org. It's a repository there, as evident by this: [image]

However, this only appears in GNOME Software; the output of `dnf repolist` is as follows:

```
repo id                        repo name
fedora                         Fedora 31 - x86_64
fedora-modular                 Fedora Modular 31 - x86_64
rpmfusion-free                 RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Free
rpmfusion-free-updates         RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Free - Updates
rpmfusion-nonfree              RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Nonfree
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates      RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Nonfree -      Updates
updates                        Fedora 31 - x86_64 - Updates
updates-modular                Fedora Modular 31 - x86_64 - Updates
```

How would I go about adding this repository so that it is available in dnf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Those extensions aren't packaged in RPM form, and DNF can only handle RPMs. GNOME Software, on the other hand, handles multiple formats beyond RPM, including Flatpaks and ... whatever way extensions.gnome.org delivers extensions.

In my experience, from the command line, the best approach is to clone the upstream git repo for whatever extension you're interested in and install with `gnome-shell-extension-tool`.